# floats smaller than FLT_MIN. why FLT_TRUE_MIN?

Tags: c, floating-point, gnu99

In an attempt to see what would happen in the case of a float underflow I found that I could make float numbers much smaller than FLT_MIN. I'm using xcode 5.1 on OS 10.9. The language dialect is gnu99.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float underflow = FLT_MIN * 0.0000004;

    printf("Float min is %f or %e.\nUnderflow is %f or %e\nMin float exp is %d.\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MIN, underflow, underflow, FLT_MIN_10_EXP);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:
Float min is 0.000000 or 1.175494e-38.
Underflow is 0.000000 or 4.203895e-45
Min float exp is -37.

1. Is there a more effective method of demonstrating the limits of data types?
2. Why is FLT_MIN not actually the smallest float value? Are there other constants that I'm supposed to be using? After typing the previous question I found FLT_TRUE_MIN. What is this number?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: Write that up as an answer, please.

Comment: You mentioned your dialect is "gnu99"; I would attract your attention that `FLT_TRUE_MIN` was introduced with C11, so formally would require using the "gnu11" dialect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2 possibilities to get "below minimum":

1. `float` range:

   Typical `float` numbers have 2 ranges: full precision (normal range) from `FLT_MAX` down to `FLT_MIN` and a 2nd range with reducing precision from `FLT_MIN` down to `FLT_TRUE_MIN`.  This 2nd range, called "subnormal" typically provides about 10^-7 more range.

   > `FLT_TRUE_MIN` is the "minimum positive floating-point number"
   >
   > `FLT_MIN` is the "minimum normalized positive floating-point number"
   >
   > `FLT_MIN_10_EXP` is the "minimum negative integer such that 10 raised to that power is in the range of normalized floating-point numbers"
   >
   > C11dr §5.2.4.2.2

   In general `0 < FLT_TRUE_MIN <= FLT_MIN <= 10^FLT_MIN_10_EXP <= 10^-37`
2. Math performed as `double`.

   `printf()` coverts each `float` passed to it to a `double`.  C allows code to optimize such that the value passed to `printf()` may be the `double` product of `FLT_MIN * 0.0000004`.

   ```
   float underflow = FLT_MIN * 0.0000004;
   printf("%e\n", underflow);
   ```

   Had the output been `4.701976e-45` rather than `4.203895e-45`, this would have been the case.

---

Note on "subnormal".  A compelling reason *for* subnormal (or denormal) numbers lies in the following problem.

```
float a,b;
... // somehow a and b are set.

// Are the 2 below equivalent?
if (a == b) foo();
if ((a - b) == 0) foo();
```

Without subnormal numbers, 2 nearly the same value numbers near `FLT_MIN` would have a non-zero mathematical difference much below `FLT_MIN` and the result would round to `0.0`.

With subnormal numbers, the difference of every pair of different `float`s is representable by something other than `0.0`.  **

** Except `+0.0, -0.0`.  Signed zeros have their own peculiarities.

Answer (score 6):

In really simple, not exact terms, floating points are stored as 0.xxxxx x 2^yyyyyy. "Normal" numbers are required to NOT have leading zeros in the xxxxx part. So the smallest number you can make is something like 0.10000 x 2^-111111. However if you "cheat" and denormalize the number you can make one like 0.000001 x 2^-111111, which is smaller but has fewer significant digits.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Answer (score 1):

Representing a floating number as `y = (+/-) significand x base ^ (exponent - precision)`, every `y != 0` has a unique representation if you make sure that `significand >= base ^ (precision - 1)`. A nonzero `y` that satisfies this is called **normalized**. Now `FLT_MIN` is the minimum normalized positive `float`, while `FLT_TRUE_MIN` is the true minimum you get without the normalized-restriction.

In other words, `FLT_MIN = base ^ (FLT_MIN_EXP - 1)` and `FLT_TRUE_MIN = base ^ (FLT_MIN_EXP - precision)`.